# Covariance with generics where type T is a

Tags: c#, .net

I need a child class to implement a method that returns a Type T, where T meets certain criteria as follows:

```
public abstract class NavEntityController<ChildEntity, GenericNavService_T_Entity ...>
  where ChildEntity : NavObservableEntity<GenericNavService_T_Entity>
{
   public abstract T ReadAll<T>(bool forceUpdate = false) where T : NavObservableCollection<ChildEntity>;
   //others
}
```

I'm trying to implement this as follows in the concrete class:

```
public class NavJobController : NavEntityController<NavObservableJob, JobCard_Service, JobCard>
    {
       public override NavObservableCollection<NavObservableJob> ReadAll(bool forceUpdate = false)
       {
                //...
       }

}

public class NavObservableJob : ...  {} //Let's just say this is a class or we are going to go down a whole tree of dependencies
```

But I get the error that my "child class does not implement inherited abstract member ReadAll from the parent".

Comment: What is the signature of the implementing class?

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the concrete class please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concrete implementation of an abstract class needs to implement the abstract members of the abstract class.

If you have a generic abstract member then you need a generic concrete implementation.

`NavObservableJob` is more specialized and specific than any `NavObservableCollection<ChildEntity>` implementation, since `NavObservableCollection<T>` is not covariant.

---

To achieve what you want, you need to define `NavObservableCollection<T>` as an interface. This will allow you to define the interface as covariant, e.g.

```
public interface INavObservableCollection<out T>
{
   // ...
}
```

**Note:** The use of the [`out` Generic Modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx).

Then change `NavObservableCollection<T>` so that it implements the new interface,

```
class NavObservableCollection<T> : INavObservableCollection<T>
{
    // ...
}
```

Then use the interface as your generic constraint,

```
public abstract class NavEntityController<ChildEntity, GenericNavService_T_Entity>
        where ChildEntity : NavObservableEntity<GenericNavService_T_Entity>
{
    public abstract T ReadAll<T>(bool forceUpdate = false)
            where T : INavObservableCollection<ChildEntity>;

    //others
}
```

Comment: So I cannot define an IEnumerable<T> as a return type in the interface and return List<T>?

Comment: @David, apologies, I was talking about the wrong class. I've amended my answer to illustrate.